# Can a gas station employee use Skimmer Scanner in TN without getting in trouble?

Tags: united-states, criminal-law, liability, fraud, tennessee

I recently ran across [Skimmer Scanner](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/gas-pump-skimmers), which is an app that uses Bluetooth to scan for, connect to, and send no-op commands to verify certain common types of card skimmers. Given that the app uses default credentials to authenticate and sends a command that does nothing but characterize the device as likely being a skimmer, would exercising this much control over an illegal/illegally installed device get someone in trouble in Tennessee? Does anything change if they are using the app as part of their work at a gas station in order to protect customers from skimmers?

The [Google Play listing](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=skimmerscammer.skimmerscammer) says

> Please check your local laws before installing this product. There is implicit risk associated with publicly reporting crimes.

The describing article says

> The app *does not* obtain or download data from a given skimmer nor does it report any information to local authorities.